# getElementByClass does it exist in vanilla js? uhn?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

```
<p id ="myP">
   
 Render this text using the myC class </p>
---------------------------
.teststyle {
    background-color:#00ff00;
    font-size: 200%;
}
---------------------
window.onload = load;           
    
function load(){
         document.getElementById("myP").className = "teststyle";
}
----------------------
```

Playing with jsfiddle.net and JavaScript I found out that `getElementByClass` is not supported in JS. I'm wondering why? What if I had a class in my XTHML-code, how can I transform this code?

The other peculiar thing I noticed is: if I use `onload = "load()"` in the xhtml won't work like if I had `"windows.load"` in the js-code; why is that? It should be the same, maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found out that "getElementByClass" is not supported in JS, uhn? funny wondering why?

Because JS has no native DOM manipulation in it. That's a separate API (provided by browsers, some other JS environments, and [libraries](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) for those other environments).

… but you probably count browser DOM implementations as part of JS for the purpose of this question so:

Because `class` isn't a generic DOM concept, it is HTML specific (or at least started out that way). `getElementsByClassName` (note **Name**!) is new in draft specifications and not all browsers have implemented it.

> so what if I had a class in my XTHML-code how can I transform this code?

You don't use getElementsByClassName in that code, so it doesn't really make much sense.

There are plenty of third party libraries that provide means to get elements based on the classes to which they belong. Some have implementations of getElementsByClassName, some just implement selector engines (such as YUI and jQuery).

> The other peculiar thing I noticed is: if I use onload = "load()" in the xhtml won't work like if I had "windows.load" in the js-code...how is dat? it should be the same, maybe it's just me..thanks!

One will overwrite the other.

Comment: about load vs windows.load = MY questions was if I was using one them separately? would it give the result? I guess not? they work differently right?

Answer (score 5):

No it doesn't, because the function's name is:

```
getElementsByClassName
//        ^       ^^^^
```

[Note that it is not support in IE before IE9.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11)

[Have a look at the documentation of `getElementsByClassName`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

Regarding the `onload` issue: Without more code it is hard to tell what you did wrong. If you do

```
<body onload="load()">
```

it will work. But doing so (attaching event handlers in the HTML) should be avoided anyway.

Comment: Hi Felix...but it still doesnt work if I change the Xhtml and write instead "class" and then ByIdClass in js?...

Comment: @YoniGeek: You would have to write `document.getElementsByClassName("className")[0]`. The method returns a node list.

Comment: @YoniGeek: What's "ByIdClass"

Comment: @Matti it was just an abbreviation of getElementsByClassName :)

Comment: @YoniGeek: Considering that your problem most likely arose from you writing the name wrong, I'd avoid abbreviating it for now...

Answer (score 1):

```
function getElementsByClassName( strClassName, obj ) {
    var ar = arguments[2] || new Array();
    var re = new RegExp("\\b" + strClassName + "\\b", "g");

    if ( re.test(obj.className) ) {
        ar.push( obj );
    }
    for ( var i = 0; i < obj.childNodes.length; i++ )
        getElementsByClassName( strClassName, obj.childNodes[i], ar );

    return ar;
}
```

Usage :

```
var aryClassElements = getElementsByClassName( 'findMe', document.body );
```

From : http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1143850&page=1

Do you guys search on google before posting here ?

Comment: stackflow is in google just kidding :) I hear u. I thought about yr idea  but then u're implemented an extra function...David is talking about why...peace bro!